# Share Internet from laptop (connected to LAN) to Android using WIFI router

Tags: networking, internet, routing, ip-forward

The idea is:
Internet - eth0 - Laptop - wlan0 - router - Android

Static IPs everywhere. IP ranges are different.

Could not establish bridge. bridge-utils unable to add wlan0 to bridge.
Android doesn't support adhoc so have to use router.

How to get Internet on Android?

Preferably keeping Network Manager installed

Answer (score 0):

On Unity go to System settings> Network. You should see a 'use as hotspot' button. after you click that you will see your hotspot's network name and password

Comment: as I know, to do this wifi adapter must be able to operate in promiscuous mode. Mine doesn't.